# A4988 current limit formula: Where does the constant "8" comes from?

Tags: current, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I am trying to calculate the VREF for my A4988 and while my A4988 is not from pololu I am using their formula over at https://www.pololu.com/product/1182 to calc the current limit.

The formula used (and seen elsewhere) is
$$
V_{REF} = 8 \cdot I_{MAX} \cdot R_{CS}
$$

Can somebody hint me to where the 8 comes from? I can figure the I and R out but the constant is not clear to me.

The only 8 I found was the minimum voltage for pololu's driver and since my driver has a min rating of 12V I kinda hesitate to go blindly with 8.

Comment: Use the formula for your product, not a different one as they may have made different assumptions.

Comment: The DACs reduce the reference voltage by 8 to make Vsense one eighth of Vref.

Comment: The datasheet (from https://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Motor-Drivers/Brush-DC-Motor-Drivers/A4988.aspx) have this on page 9. **I** tripMAX = Vref / (8xRs). Note the division, not multiplication.

Comment: @SolarMike what do you mean? My CNC shield comes with 4 A4988 drivers and neither the datasheet nor the manual of the shield provides enough information for me to figure that out :/

Comment: @Samuel He means 1. Std usually unhelpful advice given to people who buy equipment from suppliers who do not provide adequate products support. Presumably this is meant to build character or something :-). 2. If possible using the best available data is the best choice. If the best available data is from someone other than the supplier take extra extra care that there are not subtle (or not so subtle) differences that make the source less useful or dangerous. || In this case, using the Polulu data seems "safe enough". Seems :-).